# html, css or other

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a stroke to text in css:

```
color-stroke:red;
filter:glow(color=FFFF00,strength=3);
```

This apparently works in safari but I need something that will work in IE, FF, and Chrome..

Any suggestions??

Comment: Something in css that works in IE, that sounds challenging!

Comment: I don't use this as much as some... not even sure how to accept though I always get great help here..

Comment: @user154107 - Check out the [SO blog ](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/11/) for a how-to of accepting, or just try clicking [the check marks](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/uploads/stackoverflow-answers-accepted1.png) on the left of answers (you can undo it, so feel free to go crazy :P)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this doesn't work in Chrome, I would be really amused. Safari and Chrome both are based on Webkit, that features a 100% [acid3 test result](http://acid3.acidtests.org/). Maybe a matter of which extra features are activated.

According to me, the filter:glow features are actually microsoft/IE specific. This page: http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/glow_link.html has a filter with glow. It works with IE but not with chrome and not with FF.

**EDIT:**
There is a pure CSS3 feature that provides something like you want but probably not exactly the same. http://www.suburban-glory.com/blog?page=114 demonstrates it.

Unfortunately this doesn't work for IE yet. IE has pretty poor css support. I would just ignore it because the upcoming IE will solve all your trouble. So just wait a few months and you'll solve the issue with no effort to workaround a bad implementation in IE.

Comment: that works in IE however I'm just looking for a stroke.. not a glow... and cross browser compatible..

Comment: Yeah .. no that's not what I'm looking for.. I was thinking about using siFR but then I'm not sure if that's gonna give me the stroke I'm looking for..